# Redis Scan Count in production

Tags: count, redis, key

I am in the process of replacing a redis KEYS command in favor of SCAN. However, the keyspace is about 3 Million Keys. What would be a good COUNT parameter to use without affecting I/O performance?

Comment: COUNT is a trade-off - there is no "good" value, it depends on your environment and requirements

Comment: @ItamarHaber in general I think <1000 should not block redis for too long

Comment: Definitely a wise upper limit :)

Comment: @user1817347 what count do you exactly want ? do you want total number of keys in redis ?

Answer (score 0):

I am also kind of facing the same problem. But I tried this. Hope, this will help...

```
getKeyList (pattern) {
    console.log('pattern', pattern)
    let found = []
    let cursor = '0'

    while(true){
      const getAsync = promisify(this.client.scan).bind(this.client)
      const reply = getAsync(cursor, 'MATCH', pattern)
      cursor = reply[0];
      if(reply[1] != false){
        found.push(reply[1])
      }
      if(cursor == 0){
        break
      }
    }
    return found
  }
```

*Note that you have to manipulate the return as you want.

Comment: Though I have faced another problem while doing this. While searching for keys with pattern, I don't get the expected values. It just gives me the first value and maybe exits the loop or something. Let me know if you can find any solution regarding that.